# Haskell wall-time oscilator

Tags: haskell, time

I'm looking for a Haskell function which yield a value which slowly changes as wall-time elapses (and possibly wraps around after a while). I don't really mind whether it's `IO Integer` or `IO Double` or what. I just want a value that slowly changes as wall-time elapses.

Presumably there is an answer buried somewhere in the depths of the `time` package. (Or maybe `old-time`, but I presume that's deprecated?) However, the `time` package seems really, *really* complicated. And I don't actually *care* about timezones or human-readable time representations or anything. I just want a number that changes as wall-time elapses.

Can anybody show me a simple code snippet to do that? (Without me spending three days trying to figure out the complexities of the `time` package...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/systems-programming-in-haskell.html) book:

```
Prelude> import System.Time
Prelude System.Time> getClockTime
Loading package old-locale-1.0.0.2 ... linking ... done.
Loading package old-time-1.0.0.6 ... linking ... done.
Thu Jul  5 20:04:22 BST 2012
Prelude System.Time> getClockTime >>= (\(TOD sec _) -> return sec)
1341515116
Prelude System.Time> getClockTime >>= (\(TOD sec _) -> return sec)
1341515118
Prelude System.Time> getClockTime >>= (\(TOD sec _) -> return sec)
1341515121
```

Comment: Presumably this wraps around every 24 hours?

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid: no, it's [Unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), counts on forever (that's probably why it's an `Integer` rather than `Int`, though the latter is well enough for the next years...)